# How to copy data between columns based on duplicates in a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
names <- c("Smith, John", "Lu, Samantha", "Lu, Samantha", "Kumar, Vikram", "Kranski, Peter", "Kumar, Vikram")
data <- c("data1", "data2", "", "", "data3", "data4")
df <- data.frame(names, data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I need to make sure all of the names have the data associated with them in the column `data` in their row. I therefore want to paste all the data points in `data` to duplicates but only when there is an empty cell. In other words, I want an output that looks like this:

```
names <- c("Smith, John", "Lu, Samantha", "Lu, Samantha", "Kumar, Vikram", "Kranski, Peter", "Kumar, Vikram")
data <- c("data1", "data2", "data2", "data4", "data3", "data4")
df <- data.frame(names, data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am then going to use `df <- df[!duplicates(df$names),]` to eliminate duplicates so I get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
names <- c("Smith, John", "Lu, Samantha", "Kranski, Peter", "Kumar, Vikram")
data <- c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4")
df <- data.frame(names, data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you just do `df[df$data != "",]`?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately this doesn't work because there are some rows where I need to copy the data to an author before I remove the row without data. See edits to the post

Comment: This would work with your original data and the updated data.  Can you post something that is representative of your issue?  Maybe you need to use `tidyr::complete()` before deduplicating but from your example data filling the data beforehand seems redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have unique mappings from names to data in the rows that have a non-empty `data` field, you can do a `left_join` with the cleaned up version. This will generate a new column `data_complete` and you can then remove the original `data` column. Renaming at the end is optional.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df[df$data != "", ], 
          by = "names", suffix = c("_raw", "_complete")) %>% 
  select(names, data_complete) %>% 
  rename("data" = "data_complete")
```

You can also check whether your mappings are unique by checking the intermediate step:

```
left_join(df, df[df$data != "", ], 
          by = "names", suffix = c("_raw", "_complete")) %>% 
  filter(data_raw != "" & data_raw != data_complete)
```